# Multiple reference citation: can the separator be a comma followed by a space?

Tags: citing

When I use `\cite{ref1, ref2}` for multiple reference citation, there isn't any blank after the comma. I would like the reference citation to appear as follows:

> [1,  2].

How can I obtain that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you load the [cite](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package with the `space` option:

```
\usepackage[space]{cite}
```

an ordinary inter-word space will be inserted between the comma and before the next number.

If you load the `cite` package *without* the `space` option, a "thinspace" will be inserted instead. Finally, if you specify the option `nospace` when loading the `cite` package, no space will be inserted -- thus mimicking the "standard" LaTeX setting regarding the typesetting lists of citation numbers in numeric citation styles.

Comment: cite package is not compatible with `biblatex`. How can I do a similar thing with `biblatex`???

Comment: @antmw1361 - the OP didn't mention `biblatex` in his/her query. If you're interested in getting a solution that works with `biblatex`, please consider posting a new, separate and specific question to Tex.SE.