# Why there is no space between multiple references? Want [1, 2] instead of [1,2]

Tags: bibliographies

I am editing a latex document. I need to cite multiple references in the text.
Usually, I use command `\cite{paper1, paper2}` to get text like **[1, 2]**. But in a recent new document, I got **[1,2]**, with NO space after comma. I don't know why. Hope can get some help.

sample code is

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\cite{paper1, paper2}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{paper1}
Author1 and author2.
\newblock title.
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of ACL}, pages 100--102, Baltimore, Maryland,
  June 2014. Association for Computational Linguistics.

\bibitem{paper2}
Author1 and author2.
\newblock title.
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of ACL}, pages 100--102, Baltimore, Maryland,
  June 2014. Association for Computational Linguistics.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: please use a commonly available class or provide the special class for minimum working example.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer (and TeX.stackexchange.com would indeed be a better place), but ... this isn't your problem, and that's the upside of LaTeX. You're using a particular document class, `iosart2c`, and it appears that the designers of that class/layout decided that there shouldn't be spaces there, so you shouldn't try to second-guess them.

Comment: anything worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class contains the following code (line numbers added for reference):

```
696 \def\@citex[#1]#2{%
697   \let\@citea\@empty
698   \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
699     {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\hskip.1pt}%
700      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
701      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
702      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
703        \G@refundefinedtrue
704        \@latex@warning
705          {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
706        {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
```

The relevant bit is at line 699: the definition

```
\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\hskip.1pt}
```

means that multiple references will be separated by a comma, followed by an unbreakable space of 0.1pt (about 0.03mm or 0.0014in).

The standard LaTeX code has

```
\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }
```

so an unbreakable normal interword space. The class is also looking for `natbib` and, in case the package is loaded, it issues

```
\def\set@NAT@space{\def\NAT@space{\hskip.1\p@}}
```

to reestablish the same spacing as without `natbib`.

Thus the behavior you see is a precise choice by the class developers.

If you want to override it, you can, but you will annoy the copy editors: such a class should only be used for submissions to IOS Press journals.

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@citex}{\hskip.1pt}{\ }{}{} % when natbib is not loaded
\patchcmd{\set@natbib}{\hskip.1\p@}{\ }{}{} % for natbib
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{paper1, paper2}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{paper1}
Author1 and author2.
\newblock title.
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of ACL}, pages 100--102, Baltimore, Maryland,
  June 2014. Association for Computational Linguistics.

\bibitem{paper2}
Author1 and author2.
\newblock title.
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of ACL}, pages 100--102, Baltimore, Maryland,
  June 2014. Association for Computational Linguistics.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. I will add the commands later depends on editors' suggestion.

Comment: I would like to exercise similar control over the space after the comma in multiple citations using amsbook class (no natbib involved).  (In fact I would like to have no space or just .1pt.)  I have tried the patch here, and have tried directly modifying the definition of cite and citestyle in the amsbook class (lines 1303-1309 in [2015/03/04 v2.20.2]), without any success or effect.  Any ideas for how to control this in that class?  Thanks.

Comment: @Chris This is a completely new question.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I've posted it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583004/adjust-space-between-multiple-citations-in-memo-l-class
(I tried the solutions to every related question I could find, but they all seem specific to some other documentclass or package, and none had any effect in my document.)

Comment: @egreg Do you know anyone who might know how to deal with this in memo-l (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583004/adjust-space-between-multiple-citations-in-memo-l-class) I'm still stuck on this, any pointers appreciated!

Comment: @Chris Please, add a new question with the details.

Comment: @egreg Are there details that would be helpful that I didn't include here? Thanks! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583004/adjust-space-between-multiple-citations-in-memo-l-class
(I didn't catalog there the things I tried, since none of them had any effect, but as far as I know is every approach mentioned in a preexisting question/answer.)

Comment: @Chris I’ll have a look later.

Answer (score 2):

- There is another platform dedicated for tex/latex ... see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com).
- just use

  `\usepackage[space]{cite}`

you can also see a bit longer discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127020/multiple-reference-citation-can-the-separator-be-a-comma-followed-by-a-space)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12576732)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12576732)

Comment: It seems adding this command does not work in my situation. Still no space. Answers from @egreg worked. Thanks though.