# Adjust space between multiple citations in memo-l class

Tags: bibliographies, citing, punctuation, amsbook, multiple-citations

I would like to reduce (more generally globally adjust to a specific length) the space after the comma in multiple citations, while using the memo-l class.
[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
\begin{document}

Existing: Cite~\cite{1, 2}

Desired : Cite [\textbf{A},\hspace{1pt}\textbf{B}]

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem[A]{1}
Cite1
\bibitem[B]{2}
Cite2
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class does nothing to the standard `\cite` command. In the question you found that deals with a similar problem, there was `natbib` involved, that changes the processing of `\cite`.

Here it is just a matter to change the “control-space” command in `\@citex` to the spacing you'd like to get. Similarly, `\@cite` is the macro to patch for the “composite references”.

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
%\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@citex}{\ }{\hspace{1pt}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@cite}{, }{,\hspace{1pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Existing: Cite~\cite{1, 2}

Desired : Cite~[\textbf{A},\hspace{1pt}\textbf{B}]

Existing: Cite~\cite[Thm.~5]{1}

Desired : Cite~[\textbf{A},\hspace{1pt}Thm.~5]

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem[A]{1}
Cite1
\bibitem[B]{2}
Cite2
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small difference you see is because boldface is used throughout in `amsbook.cls` due to a change in `\@cite` and

```
\def\citeform#1{{\bfseries#1}}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: PS I realized there is a related matter I had forgotten to consider ... is there a similarly clean way to adjust the space after the comma in expression of the form "Cite~\cite[Thm 5]{1}"?

Comment: @Chris Added the patch.